# How to type annotate the constructor of "this" in Javascript with FlowType

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I'm having an issue with Javascript and FlowType. What I'm trying to do is return the static class so that I can easily refer to class methods within instance methods using code like `this.cls.staticProperty` Take the following example:

```
// @flow
class A {

    // This is where it fails... It cannot return Class<this>
    // ERROR: Flow: `this` type. invariant position (expected `this` to occur only covariantly)
    get cls(): Class<this> {
        return this.constructor
    }
}
```

Now, I know that I could simply fix this by specifying `A` explicitly, but then I get problems in children classes

```
// @flow
class A {

    // This works
    get cls(): Class<A> {
        return this.constructor
    }
}

class B extends A {

    static myProp: string

    doSomething(): void {

        // But, now, this doesn't work
        // ERROR: Flow: property `myProp`. Property not found in statics of A 
        this.cls.myProp = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

I could now fix this by specifying the `cls` method on `B` as well like so:

```
// @flow
class A {

    // This works
    get cls(): Class<A> {
        return this.constructor
    }
}

class B extends A {

    static myProp: string

    // I have to define this again for class B
    get cls(): Class<B> {
        return this.constructor
    }

    doSomething(): void {

        // Works now, but now I'm violating the DRY principle
        this.cls.myProp = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

Or, I could simply return `Class<any>`, like so:

```
// @flow
class A {

    // Now, we are returning the constructor of any
    get cls(): Class<any> {
        return this.constructor
    }
}

class B extends A {

    static myProp: string

    doSomething(): void {

        // Works now, but now my IDE doesn't give me auto complete
        // And I'm having to manually look up static properties and methods
        this.cls.myProp = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

But, now my IDE doesn't give me any type hints or auto complete properties on the class so I'm stuck having to type properties and methods out from memory which is error prone, not to mention how much time it takes to continually look up static methods and properties

Another solution I tried was just getting rid of the `cls` getter and instead just specifying the actual class name when I need a static property, but there are problems there too.... Consider this code:

```
// @flow
class A {

    static myProp: string

    get staticMyProp(): string {
       return A.myProp
    }
}
A.myProp = "A Hello World"

class B extends A {

}
B.myProp = "B Hello World"

let bObj = new B()
console.log(bObj.staticMyProp) // Logs "A Hello World"
// But we expected "B Hello World" since we are running it from the B instance
```

And one last option.... I could just specify `this.constructor` every time.... But I really don't want to do that... I'd rather use `this.cls` because that's what I'm used to (coming from a Python background)

```
 // @flow
class A {

    static myProp: string

    get staticMyProp(): string {
       return this.constructor.myProp
    }
}
A.myProp = "A Hello World"

class B extends A {

}
B.myProp = "B Hello World"

let bObj = new B()
console.log(bObj.staticMyProp) // Logs "B Hello World" as expected
```

I really want to be able to get the `get cls(): Class<this>` (First example above) option to work, with flow type, any suggestions? Or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to violate DRY, don't use typical inheritance hierarchies to solve common problems. It only leads to pain and heartache and *very* messy refactoring. In JavaScript / TypeScript, this is 4000% more true than in other "OO" languages.

That said, there may be some means of convincing Flow to let you pass, via F-bounded polymorphism, but it's really not going to like this, at all. Regardless of how you write this, Flow (or other sound type systems) are going to complain that you did.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.... You are absolutely right. Prototype inheritance is entirely different and forces us to re-think our entire lives... =) The plain javascript works fine... just the type checking that's complaining. And you are correct, Typescript complains when you do this too.

Comment: @RayPerea Uncle Bob would go so far as to suggest that you shouldn't be doing it anywhere, including Java, because it leads to really brittle code that's very hard to change, when you inevitably have to change it. It's hard to provide concrete examples of how you'd keep code DRY, with such a small example, but there are other, more flexible forms of code reuse, which prevent you from ever having to think about these things again. Also, if you haven't read Clean Code, I'd highly recommend it, even if you have to translate from Java to JS (flow/TS).